# Java 8 stream partitioningBy second predicate on false condition

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've been using streams as much as possible in my code recently but I've run into a problem I haven't quite been able to solve.

I have a simple class called 'Listing':

```
package models;

public class House {

private boolean isPrivate;
private Integer views;
private boolean hasSessionId;

public Listing(boolean isPrivate, Integer views, boolean hasSessionId) {
    this.isPrivate = isPrivate;
    this.views = views;
    this.hasSessionId = hasSessionId;
}

public boolean hasSessionId() {
    return hasSessionId;
}

public boolean isPublic() {
    return !isPrivate;
}

public boolean isPrivate() {
    return isPrivate;
}

public Integer getViews() {
    return views;
}

}
```

I have a list of houses where I want to produce a map containing two lists with the houses segregated via certain conditions, I want one list to contain private houses regardless of whether they have a session id and the other list to contain public houses that have a session id.

Using a traditional loop I can achieve the functionality that I want but I'd like to be able to convert it to use streams instead.

The test class below contains two tests, the first test `shouldProduceTwoListsWithOneElementEach` uses a traditional for each loop and iterates over the houses list and produces two lists, one containing privateHouses and the other containing public houses or houses with a sessionId.

The second test `shouldSeperateWhetherHouseIsPrivate` is my initial attempt at using streams, at the moment the test fails on the second assertion as the partitioningBy logic is only splitting on whether the house object is private and thus a public house that does not have a session ends up being added to the other list, accessed via segregatedHouses.get(false).

```
package models;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ListingsTest {

private List<House> houses;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    House publicListingWithSession = new House(false, 1, true);
    House privateListingWithoutSession = new House(true, 1, false);
    House publicListingWithNoViewsWithoutSession = new House(false, 0, false);

    this.houses = new ArrayList<House>();
    this.houses.add(publicListingWithSession);
    this.houses.add(privateListingWithoutSession);
    this.houses.add(publicListingWithNoViewsWithoutSession);
}

@Test
public void shouldProduceTwoListsWithOneElementEach() {
    List<House> privateHouses = new ArrayList<House>();
    List<House> publicHousesOrHasSessionId = new ArrayList<House>();

    for (House listing : houses) {
        if (listing.isPrivate()) {
            privateHouses.add(listing);
        } else if (listing.getViews() > 0 || listing.hasSessionId()) {
            publicHousesOrHasSessionId.add(listing);
        }
    }
    assertEquals(1, privateHouses.size());
    assertEquals(1, publicHousesOrHasSessionId.size());
}

@Test
public void shouldSeperateWhetherHouseIsPrivate() {
    Map<Boolean, List<House>> segregatedHouses = houses.stream()//
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(p -> p.isPrivate()));

    assertEquals(1, segregatedHouses.get(true).size());
    assertEquals(1, segregatedHouses.get(false).size());
}

}
```

So if predicate `p -> p.isPrivate()` evaluates to true then the `House` object is added to the `Map<Boolean, List<House>> segregatedHouses` that can be accessed  via `segregatedHouses.get(true)`.  If the predicate evaluates to false then the `House` is added to the other list, is there a way to evaluate the House again before it's added to the list that will be accessed via `segregatedHouses.get(false)`?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe in the second part, you want only houses that are private or ones which are public and hasSessionId partitioned into 2 lists.

Try this...

```
Map<Boolean, List<House>> segregatedHouses = houses.stream()
        .filter(p -> p.isPrivate() || p.hasSessionId())
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(p -> p.isPrivate()))
```

Comment: Hi Harsh, the problem here is that I want to collect any private houses regardless of whether they has a sessionId or not but public houses have to have a session id, so the filter means that in the test above the private house will not be added as it does not have a sessionId.

Comment: @scalabilitysolved I have updated my answer. I believe this will solve your problem